# Method does not return whole object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

When I call the method buildCommand, it does not return the property message, but I found out that if I remove some properties out of buildCommand, it works.
This is the method I call

```
const buildCommand = (commandJSON) => {
        return new Command({
        prefix: commandJSON.prefix,
        command: commandJSON.command,
        aliases: commandJSON.aliases,
        parameters: commandJSON.parameters,
        message: commandJSON.message,
        response: commandJSON.response,
        commandMedium: commandJSON.commandMedium,
        enabled: commandJSON.enabled,
        isDefault: commandJSON.isDefault,
        permission: commandJSON.permission,
        cooldown: commandJSON.cooldown,
      });
    };
```

This is how I call the method

```
const newCommand = buildCommand(commandJSON);
```

commandJSON looks like this

```
{ prefix: '!', command: 'laugh', message: 'hahaha' }
```

UPDATE 2
Here is my whole Command Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const commandSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  prefix: {
    type: String,
    default: '!',
  },
  command: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  aliases: {
    type: Array,
  },
  parameters: {
    type: Array,
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
  },
  response: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['chat', 'whisper'],
    default: 'chat',
  },
  commandMedium: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['offline', 'online', 'both'],
    default: 'both',
  },
  enabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
  isDefault: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  permission: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['everyone', 'subscriber', 'vip', 'moderator', 'broadcaster'],
    default: 'everyone',
  },
  cooldown: {
    globalCooldown:{type:Boolean, default:false},
    globalDuration:{type:Number, default:0},
    userDuration:{type:Number,default:0},
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Commands', commandSchema, 'TwitchUsers');
```

Comment: show `Command` definition

Comment: If something is going wrong it's almost certainly in that `Command()` constructor, but you did not include that code in your question.

Comment: @Anatoly, I updated my post. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: why `async/await`? Everything here seems synchronous

Comment: @JeremyThille, I had it synchronous before and changed it to async/await, since I thought that it was the problem. Im calling buildCommand in an async/await function.

Comment: Yeah so `Command` is just a Mongoose model. There's nothing async in there, you can (and should) remove the async/await stuff

Comment: Also you can simply do `const newCommand = new Command(commandJSON)`, job done

Comment: @JeremyThille, could you add your last comment as an answer, so I can accept it and close the thread?

Comment: I was precisely doing this :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command is just a Mongoose model. There's nothing async in there, you can (and should) remove the `async/await` stuff.

You can simply do `const newCommand = new Command(commandJSON)`, job done.